# Issue about Devexpress Gridcontrol in C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a devexpress gridcontrol and loaded a Xml .. If XMl has attributes then datasource getting loaded correctly .. else it fails and throws exception

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   - <hj>
          <hj /> 
     </hj>



       DataSet dsnew = new DataSet();
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader("C:\\test.xml");
        string sRdr = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sRdr))
        {
            dsnew.ReadXml("C:\\test.xml");
                  if (dsnew.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                gridControl1.DataSource = dsnew.Tables[0];
                SetGridView();
            }
```

I am getting EXCEPTIOn only if attribute is missing

Comment: what exception you are getting..

Comment: Tab is Not showed on Gridview...at first time .. without attributes tab is not getting showed

Comment: i m not getting your problem rightly. which tab is not showing on gridview. Does DevExpress Xtragrid has something like tab in it ??

Comment: Just create a xml and add some attributes to the elements and put that in dataset and put that dataset in gridcontrol u will get that treeview structure gridview in that u ill find tabs

Answer (score 0):

I never find it difficult to bind xmlDataSource to GridContorl Of Devexpress. Here is my code

```
            string strXMLPath = "Your Path Of Xml"; /* c://myxml.xml */
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(strXMLPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(fs);
            fs.Dispose();
            grdControl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q485368 .. see this download it and see the image and check with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   - <hj>
          <hj /> 
     </hj>  u can able to find the differenc